# Moving From Development to Live Site breaks CSS

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, codeigniter

Using CodeIgnitor to manange this site I have configured the css in the following location:

```
{link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo base_url();?>application/assets/css/public.css" />
```

Firebug shows me that the link points exactly where it should, unfortunately,
The problem is I keep getting 403 errors when it tries to load it.

my .htaccess file looks like this, and by the way, I don't really know what I'm looking at here:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1     !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|application/assets/js|application/assets/css|application/assets/images)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond $1 ^(images|js|css)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

How do I get this CSS to load?

Additional Info:
In that the assets folder there is also a js folder and an images folder and the favicon is NOT being pulled from that images folder either.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the configuration on that folder and/or the server are refusing you access to read the file.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Try navigating directly to the css file and you can easily confirm that you are getting a 403 error, if so it is to do with permissions.

Try accessing your development site remotely rather than from the same machine and you may see the same error there.

Comment: When accessing from another computer in the LAN the CSS renders as it should, I am leaning towards permissions as well but not sure how to set them, they are current @ 644.

Comment: I would start on the documentation for the web server you are using (Apache?) and particularly their FAQ for anything about 403 errors. It is more likely to be permissions as set up in the web server - as opposed to file system permissions but I can't really give you any more concrete suggestions sorry :(